# Hide a group in catalog product?

Tags: events, magento, observer-pattern, adminhtml

Please help me if anybody know how this work can be done.
I want to hide the website tab in catalog Product, but its functionality should exist. That is, I have made all the check boxes automatically checked,so i dont want to show this tab anybody...but at the time of adding product..check boxes values would be saved.

Comment: Can you be little clear??? Do you want the categories not to be displayed as a link in the header menu?

Comment: hi.. kvijayhari ...actually i want to hide website tab in catalog->Manage products->website tab from the left tablist.i want to hide but functionality should exist.

Comment: Why u want to do this? if u want to hide this from someone, then try creating user with restricted permissions under System->permissions->Roles and create a new user from System->permissions->Roles..

Comment: @kvijayhari that's not an option in CE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure how you would do this, but basically you need to bind an Observer in the adminhtml render sequence that calls `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs::removeTab($tabId)` where `$tabId` is the Id of the websites tab (I think it's just "websites").  The trick is to find the right event to bind your Observer to, @Joseph's [list of events](http://masteringmagento.com/2010/10/complete-events-list-for-magento-community-1-4-1-0/) should get you started.  I would try something like `adminhtml_block_html_before`.

Your observer would also set the values on the product at the same time.

Good luck,
JD

Comment: no problem.  interested to see your solution, what code worked for you?

Comment: hello...JD i tried adding an observer in config.xml and changing in removeTab() method in tabs.php inside adminhtml_block_widget...but i failed to get my desired result.So for a while i stoped my task..doing some other task...actually i am beginner in magento..but i will do that.If u have the solution please help me...

Answer (score 0):

In ProductController.php

- Websites
       */

  ```
  if (!isset($productData['website_ids'])) {
      $productData['website_ids'] = array();
  }
  ```

$productData['website_ids']=$this->getStoreWebsiteId(); //newly added

//newly added

public function getStoreWebsiteId(){

```
    $selectWebsite="SELECT * from core_website WHERE website_id!=0";
    $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
    $value=$connection->fetchAll($selectWebsite);
    foreach($value as $websiteDetails){
        $websiteId[]=$websiteDetails['website_id'];
    }

    return $websiteId;
}
```